# Java Application Architecture Guide

Tags: java, architecture, jakarta-ee

Is there a Java Application Architecture Guide that is a counterpart of this: http://www.codeplex.com/AppArchGuide ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The following should be helpful to you

1. [Core J2EE Patterns](http://www.corej2eepatterns.com/Patterns2ndEd/index.htm)
2. [Effective Enterprise Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321130006)
3. [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420)
4. [Head First Design Patterns](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596007126/)
5. [J2EE Blueprints](http://java.sun.com/reference/blueprints/)
6. [Sun Certified Enterprise Architect, Study Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130449164)

Although, having had a quick glance at the document from codeplex, I can tell you that probably 70-80% of what is in there, applies to Java as well.

Answer (score 10):

I apologize for not reading the very nice link you provided.

I will say that architecture ought to be a language-independent sort of thing.  Once you understand the principles it ought to be a matter of mapping the features and implementation details of one platform onto the other.

I hesitate to post links to any Java EE standards, because the changes made in going to EJB 3.0 make a lot of the "best practices" of earlier versions obsolete.

Object-relational mapping is now embodied in JPA; Spring has introduced ideas like dependecy injection and aspect-oriented programming.

Right now I'd say that studying [Spring](http://www.springframework.org) would give you the best insight into Java best practices for enterprise architecture.

Answer (score 5):

I am still downloading the document referenced, but from the description of the page I would think

a) A lot of it should be language independent, so it should apply to java as well.
b) Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture might fit. (this as well is Platform/language independent.) You can read about the book here http://martinfowler.com/books.html

Edit:
I just skimmed over the document. Looks really interseting. I guess I need to spend some more time with it.

The references to .NET are extremly sparse in there and mainly list the apropriate pieces of the .NET technology stack for a given ara. e.g. Windows Mobile Something for implementing the client of a mobile application. In many cases this is really just marketing.

So the equivalent for Java would be to recommend the matching Sun solution. Like MySQL for a database. While this approach makes sense for MS, which would prefer their developers to be locked into MS stuff, it does not make sense for Sun/Java which have openess as the major selling argument. So a statement like 'use MS SQL Server for this' would turn into use, Oracle, db2, mysql, ms sql server, hsqldb, derby, informix, postrgres or any other database for this ... not very helpfull. So I guess it won't happen.